# Managing & Updating State with Redux-Persist & fetch new data in Background?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-persist

I have a component that makes an API request, gets some data. Then the data is put into a child component that puts it into redux:

Pseudocode:

```
let data = await apiRequestHere(); //some graphql query, using graphql-request

return (
  <div>
    <MyReduxComponent data={data} /> //inside here, data is processed and put into redux state
  </div>
);
```

While the API request runs, I am showing a spinner.

**Redux-Persist**
Just implemented redux-persist. However, the way everything is set up right now is that the API request is made **in any case**, and the spinner is shown every time, so even with redux-persist it will wait for the data to come back from the server, making using redux-persist pointless.

How I would implement redux-persist properly and make sure that if there is data in redux-persist, use **that** data, make an API request *in the background*, and if there are any changes, then update. Don't want to block my whole app every time.

Did I go wrong in my setup here?

Comment: Are you using functional components or class components?  The code in your question isn't idiomatic React/Redux, the correct place for the API request depends on the type of component (class/functional).

Comment: This is just some pseudocode. In my functional component the api call is actually in a `useEffect`, I believe. but this doesn't really matter. What I don't understand is how I can use API calls and combine them with redux-persist, i.e., first show what's persisted & make the api calls in the background if there is something persisted, otherwise show a spinner.